# Can ctypes.data_as always be relied upon to keep references to temporaries?

Tags: python, numpy, ctypes

When passing arrays from `python` to a back-end `c++` library, can the following be relied upon? This used to work in `python <= 3.6`, but seems to result in <s>sporadic</s> crashes in `python >= 3.7`:

(this is a much simplified version of 'real' code, in which a user-facing `python` interface passes data back and forth between an underlying `c++` lib)

```
# a 2d array, possibly not order="F"
xmat = np.ones((16, 32), dtype=np.float64)

# get a pointer to a version of xmat that is guaranteed to have order="F"
# if xmat already has order="F": no temporary
# if not, a temporary copy is made, reordered and a ptr to that returned
xptr = np.asfortranarray(xmat).ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double))

# pass xptr to c++ back-end to do things (expects order="F" data)
```

As I (presently!) understand it `ctypes.data_as` [should](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ctypes.html):

> Return the data pointer cast to a particular c-types object...
>
> **The returned pointer will keep a reference to the array.**

with an additional example showing that in cases where temporaries are created, such as `(a + b).ctypes.data_as(ctypes.c_void_p)` use of `data_as` is the correct thing to do.

In `python >= 3.7` it seems that `data_as` is *not* keeping a reference to the temporary, and that in the above, `xptr` ends up pointing to deallocated memory...

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug in `python >= 3.7`? Is there a better way to do this?

---

A full example (with some additional boilerplate that marshals `array`'s into `struct`'s for the back-end library) is given here:

```
import numpy as np
import ctypes as ct

lib_REALS_t = ct.c_double
lib_INDEX_t = ct.c_int32
lib_REALS_p = ct.POINTER(lib_REALS_t)

class lib_REALS_array_t(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("size", lib_INDEX_t),
                ("data", lib_REALS_p)]

class lib_t(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
    ("value", lib_REALS_array_t)]

def bug():

    libt = lib_t()

    # a 2d array, user-specified, possibly not order="F"
    xmat = np.ones((16, 32), dtype=np.float64, order="C")

    # get a pointer to a version of xmat that is guaranteed to have order="F"
    # if xmat already has order="F": no temporary
    # if not, a temporary copy is made, reordered and a ptr to that returned
    libt.value.size = xmat.size
    libt.value.data = np.asfortranarray(xmat).ctypes.data_as(ct.POINTER(lib_REALS_t))

    # pass xptr to c++ back-end to do things (expects order="F" data)

    # just "simulate" this by trying to access data using the pointer
    print(libt.value.data[1])

    return


if (__name__ == "__main__"): bug()
```

For me, `python <= 3.6` prints `1.0` (as expected) while `python >= 3.7` prints `6.92213454250094e-310` (i.e. temporary must have been free'd, so points to uninitialised memory).

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? Also what's the *OS*, the crash rate and so on?

Comment: @CristiFati: the crash rate appears to be every time, and the `os` is various `osx`, `ubuntu`, `windows`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Listing [[Python 3.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

After investigations and looking to code I've reached a conclusion (I intuited what is happening from the beginning).

It seems that [[SciPy.Docs]: numpy.ndarray.ctypes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ctypes.html#numpy-ndarray-ctypes):

> **_ctypes.data_as**(*self, obj*)
>
> ...
>
> The returned pointer will keep a reference to the array.

is misleading. Keeping a **reference** indicates that it will hold the array (internal) buffer address (in the sense that **it won't copy the memory contents**), and **not** a *Python* reference (*Py_XINCREF*).

Looking at [[Github]: numpy/numpy - numpy/numpy/core/_internal.py](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.17.0/numpy/core/_internal.py):

> ```py
> def data_as(self, obj):
>     # Comments
>     return self._ctypes.cast(self._data, obj)
> ```

it's a call to *ctypes.cast* which only holds the buffer address of the source array.

What happens is that `np.asfortranarray(xmat)` creates a temporary array (on the fly), then *ctypes.data_as* returns its buffer address. After the line, the temporary goes out of scope (so does its buffer), yet its address is still referenced, yielding *Undefined Behavior* (***UB***).

In ***v1.15.0*** ([[SciPy.Docs]: numpy.ndarray.ctypes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ctypes.html#numpy-ndarray-ctypes) (**emphasis** is mine)) this is mentioned:

> Be careful using the ctypes attribute - especially on temporary arrays or arrays constructed on the fly. For example, calling `(a+b).ctypes.data_as(ctypes.c_void_p)` **returns a pointer to memory that is invalid because the array created as (a+b) is deallocated before the next Python statement**. You can avoid this problem using either `c=a+b` or `ct=(a+b).ctypes`. In the latter case, ct will hold a reference to the array until ct is deleted or re-assigned.

but they took it out afterwards (although the code wasn't modified (with respect to this behavior)).

To get past the error, "save" the temporary array or **keep a (*Python*) reference** to it. The same problem was encountered in [[SO]: Access violation when trying to read out object created in Python passed to std::vector on C++ side and then returned to Python (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59633363/access-violation-when-trying-to-read-out-object-created-in-python-passed-to-std/59635234#59635234).

I changed your code a bit (including those awful names :) ).

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import ctypes as ct
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict


DblPtr = ct.POINTER(ct.c_double)

class Struct0(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("size", ct.c_uint32),
        ("data", DblPtr),
    ]


class Wrapper(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("value", Struct0),
    ]


def test_np(np_array, save_intermediary_array):
    wrapper = Wrapper()
    wrapper.value.size = np_array.size

    if save_intermediary_array:
        fortran_array = np.asfortranarray(np_array)
        wrapper.value.data = fortran_array.ctypes.data_as(DblPtr)
    else:
        wrapper.value.data = np.asfortranarray(np_array).ctypes.data_as(DblPtr)
    #print(wrapper.value.data[0])
    return wrapper.value.data[1]


def main(*argv):
    dim1, dim0 = 16, 32
    mat = np.ones((dim1, dim0), dtype=np.float64, order="C")
    print("NumPy CTypes data: {0:}\n{1:}".format(mat.ctypes, mat.ctypes._ctypes))

    dd = defaultdict(int)
    flag = 0  # Change to 1 to avoid problem
    print("Saving intermediary array: {0:d}".format(flag))
    for i in range(100):
        dd[test_np(mat, flag)] += 1
    print("\nResult: {0:}".format(dd))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} {1:d}bit on {2:s}\n".format(" ".join(item.strip() for item in sys.version.split("\n")), 64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    print("NumPy version: {0:}".format(np.version.version))
    main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q059959608>sopr.bat
> *** Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ***
>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.06_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code01.py
> Python 3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 00:42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
> NumPy version: 1.18.0
> NumPy CTypes data: <numpy.core._internal._ctypes object at 0x000001C9744B0348>
> <module 'ctypes' from 'c:\\Install\\pc064\\Python\\Python\\03.07.06\\Lib\\ctypes\\__init__.py'>
> Saving intermediary array: 0
>
> Result: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {9.707134377684e-312: 100})
>
> Done.
>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.06_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code01.py
> Python 3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 00:42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
> NumPy version: 1.18.0
> NumPy CTypes data: <numpy.core._internal._ctypes object at 0x000001842ECA4FC8>
> <module 'ctypes' from 'c:\\Install\\pc064\\Python\\Python\\03.07.06\\Lib\\ctypes\\__init__.py'>
> Saving intermediary array: 0
>
> Result: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {1.0: 100})
>
> Done.
>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.06_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code01.py
> Python 3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 00:42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
> NumPy version: 1.18.0
> NumPy CTypes data: <numpy.core._internal._ctypes object at 0x000001AD586E91C8>
> <module 'ctypes' from 'c:\\Install\\pc064\\Python\\Python\\03.07.06\\Lib\\ctypes\\__init__.py'>
> Saving intermediary array: 0
>
> Result: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {9.110668798574e-312: 100})
>
> Done.
>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.06_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code01.py
> Python 3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 00:42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
> NumPy version: 1.18.0
> NumPy CTypes data: <numpy.core._internal._ctypes object at 0x0000012F903A9188>
> <module 'ctypes' from 'c:\\Install\\pc064\\Python\\Python\\03.07.06\\Lib\\ctypes\\__init__.py'>
> Saving intermediary array: 0
>
> Result: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {6.44158096444e-312: 100})
>
> Done.
> ```

**Notes**:

- As seen results are pretty random, which typically is an *UB* indicator
- What makes interesting though is that in the same run, it's always the same value (the *defaultdict* has only one item)
- Changing *flag* to *1* (or anything that evaluates to *True*) will make the problem disappear

Answer (score 0):

After some time reading about `ctypes` and looking for any breaking changes, I was able to solve this issue just by adding a proxy variable. I could reproduce the problem easily, just by pasting your sample code.

I am not very sure about why is this happening, but I can guess that assigning the pointer to another pointer directly, is buggy in `ctypes`. I will look for other possibilities too. But for now, you can solve it by adding a proxy variable like below:

```py
def bug():

    libt = lib_t()

    # a 2d array, user-specified, possibly not order="F"
    xmat = np.ones((16, 32), dtype=np.float64, order="C")

    # get a pointer to a version of xmat that is guaranteed to have order="F"
    # if xmat already has order="F": no temporary
    # if not, a temporary copy is made, reordered and a ptr to that returned
    libt.value.size = xmat.size
    temp_p = np.asfortranarray(xmat).ctypes.data_as(ct.POINTER(lib_REALS_t))
    libt.value.data = temp_p

    # pass xptr to c++ back-end to do things (expects order="F" data)

    # just "simulate" this by trying to access data using the pointer
    print(libt.value.data[1])

    return
```

**UPDATE**

Well, according to @CristiFati's answer, turns out I actually did the right thing by accident. It made sense to me to keep a reference to the actual array. I tried printing the exact location for the pointer and it changed every time. So I figured maybe if I keep it once, it won't change anymore; and it worked fine.

Very good investigation done by @CristiFati.